# Swift: How do I load Firebase data before a viewController is instantiated?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The root view of my application is a UITabBarController.

In the second tab I have a UICollectionView which is loading data from Firebase inside viewDidLoad.

I am trying to set the badgeValue for the second tabBar item based on the data inside that viewController, but the data isn't loaded until the second tab bar is tapped.

How do I load data for the second viewController before it is instantiated? Should I be loading it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set badgeValue when application starts or from another controller then you need to call API/Webservice in global method like from Appdelegate or any shared instance and then set badgeValue from that method

Comment: Ok, so If I'm using observing a .value in Firebase from my AppDelegate, & a new object is added to an array of objects,  the change is reflected in the AppDelegate.  How do I send that new object to the viewController?

Comment: Make a webservice which only returns count for updated record and use that webservice only to set badgeValue. Otherwise you can fire notification thorugh postNotification method which is not good way as I guess you only need that records for a particular viewcontroller only.